# How to refactor/rename Redux state shape when users already have locally persisted stores?

Tags: redux

I have a React Native mobile app which uses Redux and [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

Suppose the state shape currently looks like this:

```
notifications: {
    new_messages: 2,
    new_friend_requests: 0,
    new_jobs: 0
}
```

Suppose that we currently set those values with 1 reducer, where `action.notifications` is a dictionary with keys `new_messages`, `new_friend_requests`, and `new_jobs`.

```
const notifications = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NOTIFICATIONS: 
      return action.notifications;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I would like to

1. get rid of new_jobs, since it is no longer relevant
2. [split](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/SplittingReducerLogic.html) the reducer
3. rename `new_friend_requests` to `new_friend_requests_count`
4. rename `new_messages` to `new_messages_count`

The new state shape would look like this:

```
notifications: {
    new_messages_count: 2,
    new_friend_requests_count: 0
}
```

And we would have new reducers

```
const new_messages_count = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NEW_MESSAGES: 
      return action.new_messages_count;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const new_friend_requests_count = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CONNECTION_REQUESTS: 
      return action.new_friend_requests_count;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const notifications = combineReducers({
  new_messages_count,
  new_friend_requests_count
});
```

However, when I make that change, I run into an error message like this:

> Unexpected keys "new_messages", "new_friend_requests", "new_jobs" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "new_messages_count", "new_friend_requests_count". Unexpected keys will be ignored.

I understand why this happens: the user's previously persisted redux state contains those keys, and that gets rehydrated into my new Redux state shape. My question is, what is a graceful way to handle this situation?

EDIT: I realized that the error message may be entirely due to renaming the variables, and that the reducer split/decomposition may not be relevant. Still, how would you gracefully rename those variables without running into that error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that others have encountered this before, and their approach is to use version numbers, and wiping the state clean if the local version number is < the current version number

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/118